# Is this the way and appeal of data binding?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dynamic

Okay, let's see if I'm thinking straight:

If I simply want to read some data from a source and then apply it to some control, I may as well just do that directly rather than go to the trouble of data binding. IOW, I may as well do this:

```
foreach (var quad in listQH)
{
   ...
   tb.Text = quad.Ph1;
```

...as opposed to:

```
tb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", quad, "Ph1"));
```

However, if I want updates within the underlying class instance to update the controls (the "tb" textBox in this case), and user updates of the controls to update those class instance members ("two-way binding"), I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. But then, I would have to change this code:

```
List<QHQuad> listQH = GetForPlatypus(PlatypusId, dow); // listQH locally declared
foreach (var quad in listQH)
{
    int QHCell = quad.QH;
    if ((QHCell >= 1) || (QHCell <= QUARTER_HOUR_COUNT))
    {
        string PH1CellToPopulate = string.Format("textBoxA_{0}", QHCell);
        string PH2CellToPopulate = string.Format("textBoxB_{0}", QHCell);
        string PH3CellToPopulate = string.Format("textBoxC_{0}", QHCell);
        var tb = (TextBox)this.Contro.Find(PH1CellToPopulate, true).First();
        tb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", quad, "Ph1"));
        . . .
```

...to:

```
List<QHQuad> listQH; //global to the form
. . .
listQH = GetInfoForPlatypus(PlatypusId, dow);
foreach (var quad in listQH)
{
    // the same as above
```

And then I'd be able to ultimately save those potentially changed class instance values in this way:

```
foreach (var quad in listQH)
{
    UpdateQH(quad); // quad contains members QH, Ph1, Ph2, and Ph3 ("UPDATE BLA SET PH1 = :Ph1, PH2 = :Ph2, PH3 = :Ph3 WHERE QH = :QH")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Here are a few pointers, though.

INotifyPropertyChanged is only required if you want changes from within the ViewModel to bubble up to the view.  It is not required for two-way binding.  If you want two way binding and only need to read once when view loads, a plain property is fine.

You may want to check out the MVVM (Model - View - ViewModel) pattern.  It is the recommended design pattern for WPF, Silverlight, Metro, etc. because it is great for data-binding heavy implementations.

Comment: My mistake, I missed the 'winform' tag.  All content is applicable save for the declarative binding bit.  Some controls provide sufficient properties accessible from the designer that can replace that portion.

Comment: If by declarative binding you mean "tb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", quad, "Ph1"));" I've got that working. What I was wondering about is whether making changes in the controls will automatically update the "listQH" class so that in the end I can loop through it and update the database with changes the user has made.